# How to associate <textarea> with a <p> tag for accessibility (Screen Reading)

Tags: html, accessibility

I have a requirement to read text area associated with a paragraph  from screen reader. But screen reader is not reading the contents. I can achieve screen reading for a label.But not for a paragraph.

```
<div class="control-group">
            <p for="learningObjective"><span class="pe-label pe-label--bold" lang="en">Learning Objective -</span>You can enter a goal for this assignment
                that students can see.</p>
            <div class="js-listener">
                <textarea id="learningObjective" name="learningObjective" placeholder="Enter a learning goal for this assignment." ng-model="$ctrl.learningObjective" maxlength="300" ng-paste="$ctrl.removeFormatting($event)"
                 aria-label="Create Instructions. Maximum character length is 300." aria-describedby="learningObjective"></textarea>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any reason you cannot just change the `<p>` to a `<label>`? It already has a 'for' attribute, suggesting somewhere under the hood a dev wanted it to be a `<label>`.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> <textarea id="learningObjective" [...] aria-describedby="learningObjective"></textarea>
> ```

The `aria-describedby` attribute point to the textarea tag. Make it point to the `id` of the `p` tag. (and remove the `aria-label` within the same time)

Comment: And take the max character count and stuff it into the label text. No reason to restrict that information just to SR users.